# Transform feature space to make points linearly separable?

Tags: transformation

I am trying to figure out an appropriate transformation of the x1 and x2 features such that one can make this linearly separable while keeping the dimensions of the feature space below 3 so that we can visualize it. I have tried various transformations such as ReLU, tanh, squaring, etc, but to no success. Any guidance?

[features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6uQ6.png)